# Mix shader is not working

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I am new to Blender. Now I am trying to create an animation where the color of the body will disappear after sometime. For that, I am using node editor and in it I am adding a mix shader and transparent shader. Now in the material preview in the properties editor the body is disappearing as I change the value of the mix shader. However, in the scene it is not disappearing. Also, in the animation, the body is not disappearing. I am using the Cycles render engine. Kindly help me with this.

[image]

Comment: are you talking about the red button? It doesn't disappear in Solid mode but it does in Render mode, as expected... so I don't know what is the problem

Comment: Hi it was my mistake .I was not looking into the rendered view.Sorry for taking your time.but now I have another issue.In the rendered view the bodies are getting shaky and distorted.Can u please tell how to solve it?

Comment: If you have an answer you should write it in the answer box below. If you have a new question, this should be asked separately.

Comment: Sorry I am new here so didn't knew the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, someone should write an answer, because long ago, I got stuck on such things. (Of course I *never* get stuck now :P)

If the red disk is supposed start off solid red and fade into invisibility at 50 frames in, then it works fine.  It may not look so in the 3D view, unless you have VIewport Shading set to  Rendered mode (the small button just right of the Object Mode / Edit Mode button.)  Textured, Material and Solid view shading modes won't show animation of textures.[image: Veiwport shading menu in 3DView menu bar]